# Can't get the current value of aria-pressed by doing .attr()

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, togglebutton

I am using this bootstrap toggle: https://codepen.io/aanjulena/pen/ZLZjzV

Essentially it's reskinning a button. Whenever the value is "on" the `aria-pressed` attribute is true and vice versa. Like so:

```
<button id="packagesSwitch" type="button" class="btn btn-toggle my-3 pkgSwitch" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
                            <div class="handle"></div>
                        </button>
```

I'm trying to get this value with jquery by doing:

```
$('.pkgSwitch').click(function(){

                if($(this).attr('aria-pressed')){
                    console.log("true");
                    $('#packageSwitchValue').val(1);
                }else{
                    console.log("false");
                    $('#packageSwitchValue').val(0);
                }
            });
```

However it doesn't seem to work at all. I realize that `.attr` gives me the original value and I tried somehow using `.prop()` but I can't think of a way to do so since nothing I try works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of the attribute value returned here is 'string' - you can check this with `typeof()`. If you change the `if` statement to add `=== 'true'` it should work.

```
if($(this).attr('aria-pressed') === 'true'){
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code to get the value from the `aria-pressed` attribute seems working fine. However, the value is actually a string, so it must be evaluated on a different way. Also remember that every call to the DOM must be done after the `load` event gets triggered on document, to ensure everything is ready to query. Oherwise, jQuery would not be able to find the required node:

```
$(function() {
  $('.pkgSwitch').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('aria-pressed') === "true"){
      console.log("true");
      $('#packageSwitchValue').val(1);
    }else{
      console.log("false");
      $('#packageSwitchValue').val(0);
    }
  });
});
```

However, the `data-toggle` behaviour seems to update the node attibutes after the `click` event is triggered, causing unpredictable results (Sometimes could be true or false because there's no order on listeners registered on node). Maybe adding some debouncing or just a simple `setTimeout` could fix the issue. Also, you must watch for `active` class changes instead `aria-pressed`, because this is an accesibility-only argument.

```
const WAIT_MS = 50;

function onToggleUpdate($elem, cb) {
  setTimeout(() => cb($elem.hasClass("active")), WAIT_MS);
}

function cb(val) {
  console.log(!!val ? "true" : "false");
}

$(function() {
  $('.pkgSwitch').click(function() {
    onToggleUpdate($(this), cb);
  });
});
```

I attach a CodePen with the concept working: https://codepen.io/geekzolanos-dev/pen/YzXpdzV